# Collecting usage data On-Demand application (php+javascript)

Tags: javascript, php, collections, usage-statistics

I need to collect usage information on my on-demand application.
This should include things like forms opened, time on form, buttons clicked etc.
Data collected should be kept in a database (MongoDB) or file system.
Is there a standard way to do so and/or an open source project for this?

Comment: http://piwik.org/ which is OS does not offer event tracking yet, where Google Analytics (non-OS) should do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on amount of details you planing to collect, first of all, I would suggest you to check with Google Analytics, pretty much what they done is possible to replicate. If you just need to know which button/link on page people clicking more, you can use something like a [ClickHeat](http://www.labsmedia.com/clickheat/index.html)